# VS2015 DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. (0x80070005)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I cannot deploy a DirectX 12 universal App. My troubled evening started with signing errors, with VS20015 complaining that the automatically generated MyDx12App_TemporaryKey.pfx was not valid for signing.

```
Error       DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed.  (0x80070005) MyDx12App           
Warning APPX0106    Loading certificate file 'MyDx12App_TemporaryKey.pfx' failed. Errore non specificato.
    MyDx12App   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets   1908    
Warning APPX0106    Loading certificate file 'MyDx12App_TemporaryKey.pfx' failed. Errore non specificato.
    MyDx12App   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets   1908    
Warning APPX0107    The certificate specified is not valid for signing. For more information about valid certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478.   MyDx12App   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets   1908
```

Actually, that PFX file was created empty (0 bytes) by Visual Studio. I created a valid certificate by doing:

```
Solution Explorer > Package.appxmanifest > Packaging > Choose Certificate... > Create test certificate...
```

By doing this, I got rid of the signing errors (which, very interestingly, would not appear on a second and subsequent redeploys after a clean, even with the corrupted certificate, which leads me into thinking that maybe that wasn't the real problem).

Anyway, with this fix I was able to get rid of the signing errors, even when trying to redeploy after a clean; but the first error of the log:

```
DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed.  (0x80070005)
```

Never went away, and kept me good company for the best part of the evening.

I tried everything I could find with Google, however my case seems different because the error message doesn't specify any sub-error, although it does say that it is an Access Denied error (0x80070005).

Things I tried:

- Use a local account
- Disconnect VS from my Microsoft Account
- Change Package name (in the manifest)
- Change Version (in the manifest)
- Change Publisher display name
- Recreate the PFX certificate again
- Disable and re-enable developer mode
- Allow the SYSTEM user to fully control the solution directory
- Turn my account into administrator (I can do it because I also have an administrator account on this PC).

Nothing worked. My machine:

```
Visual Studio: Community 2015, 14.0.25123.00, Update 2

Windows 10
  Version: 1511
  OS Build: 10586.318
```

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that I failed to give SYSTEM full control. You need to use the Advanced security settings, to apply permissions recursively. The correct procedure is:

- Right click on the solution directory
- Click Properties
- Click Security
- Click Advanced
- In the Authorization tab click Add
- Choose SYSTEM as the entity
- Select Full control
- Click Ok
- Check "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object"
- Click Ok

Answer (score 6):

For future viewers,

I found that this error is also generated if you have any of the files within your apps package folder open. In my case, I had the SQLite database file open in a viewer and that caused VS2015 to fail with a DEP0700 error.

Comment: Bingo! I had the sqlite db open externally. Closed it, and error dissapeared. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try to close Visual Studio and any Simulator. Then, as administrator, go to 
directory %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages (usually in C:\Users\%username%).
Then, delete the directory with the name of your package (a dir with a name like nnnn.Yourname.YourAppName_xxxxxxxxxxxxx).
Then restart Visual Studio and try to deploy again.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the DEP0700 error with my new created Xamarin.forms project (stored on a **network-drive**) and VS2015 Update3 RC. 
After I have changed the output directory from the network-drive to a local directory (as fast workaround), the error has gone...
You can find the details here [Problem Xamarin.forms on a network-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683126/visual-studio-2015-update-2-registration-of-the-app-failed-0x80073cf6)

Comment: This was my root cause of the issue in a VS2017 UWP app.

Answer (score 3):

There is another reason for deployment failing with a permissions error - if the solution directory is protected with Windows EFS!

In fact, UWP applications don't seem to like EFS at all.  They won't open a file that is encrypted with EFS.

I'm new to UWP but this seems like a major shortcoming.

Comment: I also had the DEP0700 error with registration of the app failed. (0x80070005) in VS2019. The solution was to not encrypt the project folder with EFS.

Comment: I suffering from this ailment myself, I was suspecting it could be the case, but I refused to believe it.. So if I need to comply with a client requirement to have their files encrypted while working on their project in my local machine.. I can't?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue (`error APPX0106: Loading certificate file 'MyCert.pfx`) and tryed every solution but nothing worked for me. 
In fact their was a **new line** after the key name in the `.csproj`:

```
<PackageCertificateKeyFile>MyCert.pfx
</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
```

Removed it and it worked.