# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2: Registration of the app failed. (0x80073cf6)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I'm experiencing the Registration of the app failed. (0x80073cf6) error.

What I've tried so far:

- Delete the package in AppData (I can't find it anymore there, the package family name has been changed to my associated store listing).
- Repair Visual Studio
- Acquire developer license
- Make a new project (that works, for the 1st time, after that same error).

It happens on my phone (950XL, developer unlocked) and on my machine.

I can't debug my app in anyway now.

I'm on Update 2 of VS 2015

Comment: anything in the Output Windows - Build tab ?

Comment: Hi Alex, This is the output from VS.
 2>------ Deploy started: Project: CloudMusicBeta, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Updating the layout...
2>Copying files: Total 5 mb to layout...
2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
2>Registering the application to run from layout...
2>DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed.  (0x80073cf6)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Same result when I choose for x86 (this was the deploy to 'Local Machine').

Comment: I just started getting the same error but for an App I am converting from 8.1.

Comment: I finally found the reason for why I was getting this message. It's the pngs I was using, which came from my 8.1 project. After I got rid of those and used the ones that were generated by Visual Studio the error went away. There are some rules around these bitmaps that I do not understand yet.

Comment: Rhndy does @ezaspi's solution work for you too?

Comment: The error is a general one, and the incorrectly created pngs is one thing that can trigger the error. Hence, I am not offering it as a "solution" but an FYI.  Should anyone have the same issue, here is a link for creating the store pngs: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/madenwal/2015/11/24/generating-your-tileicon-image-assets-for-windows-10-uwp-using-photoshop-actions/

Answer (score 1):

In the question, the project-type is not specified, but I think, it can be the same problem, I have...
I have installed **VS2015 Update 3 RC** and created a **Xamarin.Forms shared** project from template (without any changes in the project).
Same error for UWP- and Windows 8.1 projects, where Windows Phone 8.1 works in the emulator.
I store my project on a **network-drive** (what never was a problem with earlier .forms-projects, that have **not** included UWP- and Windows 8.1-projects).
I have changed the Output path from \bin\debug\ (=sub-directory of the project folder **on the network drive**) to C:\Temp\Debug and... **the error has gone**.
So.. it seems as (at least Xamarin-) UWP- and Windows8.1-projects have a problem, when the output-directory points to a network drive.
This is not a final solution for projects on a network-drive, but a workaround to be able to develop until the real problem can be solved (I hope for some changes in VS or a clear advice, what to change regarding the rights of the network drive to solve the problem from MS).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Name</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Other Name</PublisherDisplayName>
<Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
```

In the app manifest file, change the "Name" to anything else. And it'll work.
That is it.